# Floating votes tab on new profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

I just noticed that there is a ‘votes’ tab under the regular tab bar on the activity tab of my own profile.

The following screenshots are from Chromium 41 on Arch Linux:

#### Summary tab:

[image: summary tab]

#### Tags tab:

[image: tags tab]

#### Votes tab:

[image: votes tab]

Comment: Please remember to mention your browser and version as well as the system it is running on. I don't see that on my firefox 37.0 for example. Also, it is often helpful [to highlight](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/203101) the relevant part of an image so the bug can be found easily.

Comment: Sorry about that, completely slipped my mind. Should have written it down instead of posting a question right away when I had to go, ey.

Comment: Actually, I can no longer reproduce it in Chromium after a reboot. I’ll see if it happens again, and if it doesn’t reoccur I’ll post an answer saying so tomorrow.